# Update SQL query set

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

```
UPDATE tab1
SET col = 1
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.ID = tab1.ID
WHERE tab2.ID IS NULL
```

Where do I put the `ELSE col = 0`in this query?

Comment: so when tab2.ID IS NOT NULL then col should = 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tab1
SET col = CASE WHEN tab2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.ID = tab1.ID
```

I assume you want col to be 1 when tab2.ID is NULL and 0 when it is not.  So you need to do 2 things.  Use a case expression.  Also remove your where expression so that you are not limiting the results table to only tab1 rows that have no relation to tab2